Advice needed for publishing a math paper
I am an under grad student and have prepared an original manuscript which revolves around numerical identities of zeta function.
Since it is written not using overly advanced mathematics, I am confused on which journal do I send it?
I wish to apply to a reputable grad school in the future and was wondering if the journal "prestige" would affect my CV
Some few journal i had in mind were notices/Bulletin AMS or the MAA but maybe my work could be best suited for other journals? This would by my first time publishing a paper and any advice would be of great help!

Ask a professor at your university - they'll both know better, and be able to examine your paper and offer suggestions.

Congratulations on your achievement.
Doing Mathematics in a popular field can be difficult as you need to know what else is out there. I hope you have a good library at your disposal so that you can find some existing literature. This will allow you to put your discoveries into context, even though you might find out that your results have already been obtained by others. Simpler proofs of known results are of course still interesting and often publishable. You should start out by doing searches in Google Scholar and if available, Mathematical Reviews and Zentralblatt. A trained librarian would be very helpful. You might also approach a faculty member who can help you.
Getting to know the literature on zeta functions will answer your original question. For example, if you found that you have obtained a new simpler proof of a known result, you have now seen similar articles and seen where they were published. Of course, the most likely outcome of a literature search is the realization that you rediscovered something already known. That would make your result unpublishable, but would not diminish your achievement. If you found something entirely new using elementary methods, you might have something that should be published in the very top journals.
There is a lot involved in Mathematical Research. If you can find a trained Mathematician that is willing to mentor you, this would be most beneficial for your development as a mathematician.
